# How to generate csv file with ajax call in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, csv

I am working with **PHP AJAX DATATABLE** (in drupal). I am making a function to generate csv file of the table record. 
I create a button to click (in html) to access that link (or if i am calling it by url. )

I did it and my function(php Function) is working fine.

But how can i create a csv on depends on searched values ? I dont want to refresh my page and i think ajax call help me.

But how to handle my csv file creation function in ajax call.

**My php function**

```
/* testing the excel output */
function export_to_excel_page() {
    //testing 
    $filename = "file_name.csv";
    $row_array = db_query('SELECT recipient_name , year , title , sector , region , commitment_million_inr   FROM {#######} ');
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; utf-8');
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('recipient_name', 'year', 'title', 'sector','region','commitment_million_inr' ));
    foreach($row_array as $key => $value) {
        fputcsv($output, (array)$value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question needs a lot more clarification of what your specific problems are. As it stands now it is not clear at all what you are asking

Comment: I am not able to handle the the csv working in ajax call .

Comment: but what does that mean? What ajax call, none is shown? Break this down into specific parts

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an on click event you can use the JQuery $.get function to do what you want.

```
//change #button to whatever id or class name you are using in your html
$("#button").on("click",function(){//begin on click event


$.get("place path to the csv here",function(data){//begin function


  //Use the data parameter passed in to the function to manipulate(parse)
  //your data returned from your csv file here.


    //if you want to see if there is a string inside of the data
    //indexOf returns -1 if the item is not found
    //Check to see if the searchterm is found or is not equal to -1
    if(data.indexOf("searchterm") !== -1){//begin if then

     //Do something if you find the searchterm string.

    }//end if then



   //if they are comma seperated values you can first

   //turn the csv into an array
   var csv = data.split(",");

   //loop through the array do whatever you need to do
   for(var i =0; i < csv.length; i++){//begin for loop

      //if the array index equals the string something
     if(csv[i] === "something"){//begin if then

         //do something like turn the csv into an undordered list


       }//end if then


   }//end for loop



});//end function


});//end on click event
```